# uploading image with extension not working

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

i am trying to upload an image and saving image name in database as the session name with extension .jpg
i got problem that only the image name saved in database not the extension. i am using this code

```
Dim strPath As String = Server.MapPath("~/UserPics/")
        If AsyncFileUpload1.HasFile Then
            AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(strPath & Session("UserName").ToString() & ".jpg")
            lblUploadMessage.Text = "You uploaded " + AsyncFileUpload1.FileName
            con.Open()
            Dim objCmd As New SqlCommand("insert into regist( image1) values ('" & Session("UserName").ToString() & "')", con)
            objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
        Else
            lblUploadMessage.Text = "Please select an image first"
            Return
        End If
```

Comment: As as side note, are you sure the uploaded image is a jpeg image. It could very well be a PNG imgae or TXT file as far as I can see from the code.

Comment: 1. It is inserting only the session name because that is all you are putting into the SQL, a 2) Use SQL parameters at all times, to avoid SQL Injection.

Comment: Little bobby tables would have fun with this code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change

```
Dim objCmd As New SqlCommand("insert into regist( image1) values ('" & Session("UserName").ToString() & "')", con)
```

to

```
Dim objCmd As New SqlCommand("insert into regist( image1) values ('" & Session("UserName").ToString() & ".jpg" & "')", con)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not inserting the same string you are saving, you have to add the extension see below.  Also, add the extension from the file posted instead of hard-coding:

```
Dim objCmd As New SqlCommand("insert into regist(image1) values ('" & _
    Session("UserName").ToString() & _
    System.IO.Path.GetExtension(AsyncFileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName) & "')", con)
```

Please change you code to using parameters in order to prevent SQL Injection attacks:

```
Dim objCmd As New SqlCommand(con)
Dim sql As String = "insert into regist(image1) values (@image)"
Dim param(1) As SqlParameter
param(0) = New SqlParameter("@image", SqlDbType.VarChar)
param(0).Value = Session("UserName").ToString() & _
      System.IO.Path.GetExtension(AsyncFileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
objCmd.Parameters.AddRange(param)
objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()
```